# How to get MSVS to recognized the bigobj flag?

Tags: c++

I am building a User Defined Function in ANSYS Fluent which calls my installation of MSVS 2017 to compile the code. The problem is I get the error:

fatal error C1128: number of sections exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj

I have found others with this problem, but I still have not been able to figure out how to add a line in my code to get the compiler to recognize this. Based on finding other snippets of code online, I have tried to add the lines after the includes at the top of the code:

```
#include "udf.h"
#include "unsteady.h"
#include "dynamesh_tools.h"
ADD_DEFINITIONS(/bigobj)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /bigobj")
```

But this gives the errors:

```
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(10): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '/'
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(10): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '/'
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(10): error C2059: syntax error: '/'
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(10): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

I don't understand these errors, as these were copied from someone else's working code.  I also tried, from a different snippet I found online:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -bigobj
```

But this gives the error below.

```
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(9): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '+='
..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(9): error C2059: syntax error: '+='
```

This is the top of my udf file, which runs until I add too many lines to it and get the error shown above.

```
#include "udf.h"
#include "unsteady.h"
#include "dynamesh_tools.h"
```

I expect the code to compile but it doesn't. I have not found any solution that shows exactly how to tell the compiler what it tells me I should tell it.

Comment: It is /bigobj, not -bigobj

Comment: Hello Michael Chourdakis, I assume you are referring to my second attempt?  I tried this line instead, based on your suggestion:





    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /bigobj





But I got the error:





    ..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(9): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '+='
    ..\..\src\MY_UDF.c(9): error C2059: syntax error: '+='

Comment: The CMake and QMake is not C++ code, and must not be in the source. Rather, it's a build system configuration line and should be in your buildsystem files.

Comment: Hello Guillaume Racicot,

Do you know of any way to put something in the source code to tell the compiler to do what it is telling me to tell it to do?

Thanks

Comment: @user3113647 The problem is not the source code. The problem is in how you compile the said code. You have to invoke the compiler differently. You surely either use CMake, QMake, MSBuild, Meson or others. Refer to the documentation of the one you use to add the correct compiler flags.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume Racicot, but I have no choice about how to compile the code.  ANSYS Fluent calls MSVS and compiles the code on its own.  I cannot give Fluent any information beyond where the source file is located.  Do I understand you to mean there is no way for me to tell the compiler what to do from in the source code?  Thanks!

Comment: @user3113647 There is little to do when the compilation already started.

Answer (score 0):

You must just add a `/bigobj` to the `makefile_nt.udf` file of Fluent.

> In that file you will see these lines:

```
# compile flags
#  /c for compile only,  /Za for ansi c and __STDC__ is set
CFLAGS = /c /Za /DUDF_EXPORTING /DUDF_NT /DWIN64 /EHa /wd4224
```

> Simply add /bigobj as the last flag.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5043c081-a317-4528-a02d-d4b6e6d21543/problem-with-bigobj-when-compiled-by-other-software?forum=msbuild)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference only. The link may become invalid or its content gets removed, leaving then your answer without the actual explanation.